# How to check NSString isEqualToString for a lot of values

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, nsstring

I am looking for the most efficient way to match an NSString against about 200,000 other strings in the minimum amount of time. Basically I need to check, every once in a while, whether or not a word that is inputted is part of the English language.

What are the ways I could do this? I've heard about hashtables-- is that the best way?

---

### Here is the code I settled on:

**EDIT:
benchmarks for dictionary initialization to memory:**

```
NSDate *start = [NSDate date];

NSLog(@"initWords");

//temporary 
NSString *_filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:kFILE_NAME_FOR_DICTIONARY ofType:@"txt"];

NSLog(@"%@",_filePath);

NSString *_fileContents = [[NSString alloc] init];
NSData *_binary = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:_filePath];  

if (_binary) {  
    _fileContents = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:_binary encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}  else {

    NSLog(@"file parse error: did you forget to add the file? Please add file to:\n\n\n\n%@\n\n\n\n",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]);
}

NSArray *_wordList = [_fileContents componentsSeparatedByString:kNEW_LINE_CHAR];

englishDictionary = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
[englishDictionary addObjectsFromArray:_wordList];

NSLog(@"Word count:\t%d",englishDictionary.count);
NSLog(@"Time to init dictionary:\t%f",[start timeIntervalSinceNow]*-1.);
```

iphone 5: 1.089725 (seconds)

ipad   1: 3.082753

iphone 4: 3.582853

**Benchmark (time to test word if it is in the dictionary or not):**

```
-(BOOL)checkWord:(NSString *)word{

    NSDate *start = [NSDate date];

    BOOL yesNoMaybeSo = [englishDictionary containsObject:word];

    NSLog(@"Time to check word:\t%f",[start timeIntervalSinceNow]*-1.);
    return yesNoMaybeSo;

}
```

iphone 5: 0.000021 (seconds)

ipad   1: 0.000037

iphone 4: 0.000043

Comment: If you are storing it anywhere then go for dictionary, it will be faster to retrieve and search for existence as compared to array.

Comment: Hmmm what about an NSSet then? How much memory do you think I will eat up by just having a set that large floating in memory?

Comment: Does the ~200,000 strings ever change?

Comment: Consider core data and entities, that way you can use predicates to find out if the same string exists or not. Also, this will give you a lot more flexibility when it comes to memory management etc

Comment: @Srikanth : i agree with you. But dictionary, set, array... what data structure shuold he use?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya A set would be the best.

Comment: I recommend using a database such as SQLite. If you want them all in memory try [`NSHashTable`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSHashTable_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NSHashTableOptions) if you are targeting iOS 6+.

Comment: If all you want to do is find out if a string exists, then you can just execute fetch request and find that out right. I know this is not the conventional way of doing, but it gives a lot of flexibility, faster start up time, additional customization options etc. For example, even if the number of words are 200,000 in each language, you can just execute a different query with a predicate and you are done.

Comment: @Joe the strings would never change. I've been looking more and more into NSSet and that looks like a good option. Additionally I can split up the NSSet for 200k into 7k sets depending on what letter the word starts with.  Anybody have any guesses regarding the execution time?

Comment: Have looked at SQLite or CoreData? Using an NSSet means you have to load the 200k strings into memory every time the application is initially launched. A database would allow you to bundle the strings or store them once, and with indexes it is quite fast.

Comment: @Joe take a look at the edited question for the benchmarks... could sqlite compare to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way is probably to use a `NSSet` to store all the words you want to compare against your string.

Then you simply check whether your word belongs to the set like follows

```
BOOL englishWord = [theEnglishSet containsObject:yourString];
```

This will take constant time to perform.

Comment: "most efficient" that is a bold claim.

Comment: I've been looking more and more into NSSet and that looks like a good option. Additionally I can split up the NSSet for 200k into 7k sets depending on what letter the word starts with. Anybody have any guesses regarding the execution time?

Comment: @Joe take a look at the edited question for the benchmarks... could sqlite compare to that?

Answer (score 1):

With such requirements standard methods/classes will not fit your needs. You should learn/read some books on algorithms to implement this correctly. Looks like you should use hash tables, but, again, with 200K values NSDictionary (which is hash table) probably will not work fast enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind rolling your own, you can build a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (a.k.a prefix tree) from the dictionary and use it to look up the words. I'd bet a reasonably good implementation using c strings and structs would be faster and more memory-efficient than an NSDictionary.